# Find and Replace method ending brackets

Tags: c, regex

Is it possible to do a find and replace in Visual Studio to replace the ending brackets of a specific set of functions (all of which have the same signature) with a set of brackets?

Replace this:

```
int foo(int)
{
    something;
}
```

With this:

```
int foo(int)
{
    something;
}
}
```

The only way I have been able to come up with that doesn't involve copy/paste is using regex to recognize this:

```
}

int foo2(int)
```

and replace with this:

```
}
}

int foo2(int)
```

which takes advantage of the fact that most of the matching functions are in order.  It still isn't perfect as it will miss the last one in a sequence.  A cleaner way would be nice, but I'm not sure that there is one.  The only reason I suspect there might be is because of intellisense.  I thought that maybe I could take advantage of the fact that visual studio knows when a function starts and ends.

Trust me, in my specific case, it makes syntactic sense to do so.  Thank you.

Comment: Visual Studio's auto complete feature can be turned off. Option->Editor->C/C++->IntelliSense=False

Comment: @lulyon how would that help?

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood you question. I thought you meant to some editing, but with intellisense, the editor add something messy. So the solution is to turn off intellisense.

Comment: @lulyon No, intellisense isn't causing any problems, I was thinking that it might actually provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a cleaner solution with just regex. Unfortunately, while regular expressions can match patterns, they cannot represent *grammar*, e.g., match opening and closing brackets.

To explore this a little, let's say I wrote some regex to find an opening bracket, accept other characters, then a closing bracket. This wouldn't work because in the case of

```
void foo()
{
    if (bar)
    {
    }
}
```

it would match the opening bracket of foo, and the closing bracket of bar. We need some way to *count* the opening and closing brackets, and regular expressions do not give us any ways to do so.

This is why compilers generally break reading your code into two main steps:

1. Scanning, where code is broken into tokens such as `void`, `foo`, `(`, `)`, `{`}, etc. This can be done with regular expressions or code that matches tokens in a similar manner.
2. Parsing, where the tokens are organized based on the language's grammar, usually resulting in an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)

Comment: Right, that's why I was wondering if it was possible that intellisense might be able to help, because it detects and pairs the matching closing bracket to the appropriate opening one.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could tap into Intellisense like that.

Comment: Neither am I, that's why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score -1):

I once did the similar work.
You can put

```
^{:i:b+:i\(.*\).*\n\{\n(:b+.*\n|:Wh\n)*}\}
```

in "Find what input box" and

```
\1}\n}
```

in "replace with input box".

The above finding pattern can find any code block in following form:

```
xxx xxx(xxxxxxxxx)
{
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
}
```

and replace it with:

```
xxx xxx(xxxxxxxxx)
{
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
}
}
```

If you still don't know how to use Regular Expressions in visual studio, see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: What keeps this from matching a nested end brace, such as the example in my question?

Comment: @slavik262 match a '}' without leading space or tab. If code isn't indented, this will fail.